# How can I find my PPSSPP saves in Ubuntu?

Tags: emulation, psp, ubuntu

I am using the "PPSSPP" PSP emulator in Ubuntu but I don't know where the save files are, so I can't create a backup copy.

Does anyone know a method to do so?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The PPSSPP Emulator saves to the **`memstick\PSP\SAVEDATA`** subfolder in the PPSSPP directory.

ie. `...\{PPSSPP installed directory}\memstick\PSP\SAVEDATA`

If you have built the emulator from source files, it will be located in `/home/[user]/.config/ppsspp/PSP/SAVEDATA`.

From here you can just copy either the entire folder, or relevant files/folders and then store the copy somewhere else. If you need to restore your backup just move the copy back.

Comment: i've already tried searching for those. Actually there is no memstick directory related to the emulator. There is a "PPSSPP" directory only with a subdirectory called "assets" but no save files.

Comment: @null_ did you build it from source?

Comment: You may find it here: `/home/[user]/.ppsspp` if you did.
Otherwise you can try just searching your computer: `find / -type d -name "ppsspp"` and repeat with ".ppsspp"

Answer (score 0):

The saves are at /home/"user"/.config/ppsspp/PSP/SAVEDATA.

.config is a hidden folder so you need to check the necessary options to enter without without the console, right click at your home folder -> "Show hidden files" or something like that on Debian using Cinnamon.

It's different from Windows, where the saved games' folder is in the same folder of the executable.
I didn't compile my PPSSPP and I was surprised that I needed to go looking for the saves (PPSSPP v1.5.4).

Hope this helps.